# Bootstrap dropdown panel jumps in front of the panel above

Tags: html, css, height, dropdown, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue using the Bootstrap dropdown panel. I have 4 main panels and each one of them contains some more bootstrap panels. When I open 1 at a time there is no problem but when I start opening more panels the position of the panels start to change. They start to overlap and interfere with each other. Already did some research in the Bootstrap documentation but can't find any solution to it. I hope you guys can help me out!

Link to the web page: http://37.252.123.22/~profsb/europe/en/form-test-page/

The problem seems to be the worst with the 3rd panel ('Grooved products').

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: Honestly I haven't looked for the problem in depth, but I've noticed that if you remove the class "panel" from the divs, there is not any bug. So I think the problem could be in the classes that are related with that one

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself as the external link will change a no longer be useful to future readers of this question.

Comment: Also, if you're using Bootstrap 4 why not use card instead of panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi be careful with the `data-parent="#accordion"` declaration I'm seeing in your code that you set that same value even for inner accordion, try set up a custom name for each of the inner accordion.

This is causing the issues collapsing